# Microsoft Windows Embedded Studio download

Tags: windows, embedded, rtx

I have a Win XP Embedded machine (WES2009), that does not have preinstalled "Microsoft Windows Embedded Studio" (MSWES).
I need MSWES as a preposition for development (RTX by IntervalZero).

All I found on MS site related to  this product is docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838630(v=WinEmbedded.5).aspx

Anyone with a clue:

1. Can I simply install MSWES product on my WES2009 machine ?
2. Where can I download it simply ? (Preferably without using MS account.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't run Embedded Studio on XP Embedded; you run it on your development host, and use it to create an XP Embedded OS image for your target application.

You need a development license, and ultimately deployment licenses.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply and officialy download the WES2009 here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=14947

This should be a trial version, or you apply your bought licence to this.